# Binding double to Textbox with validation in windows store apps

Tags: c#, validation, xaml, windows-store-apps, prism

I am using prism for windows 8 the BindableBase class to validate the properties, till now I can bind the string properties and validate them with custom validator.

Now I want to bind the double value directly to the view with two way binding.the problem is when user enters any alphabetical character then the setter of that double property doesn't gets fire cause its not a double value and might fires a conversion exception but because of that I cant validate my property.

may I go for the converter ?, but how can I raise validation exception and make the property invalid in converter

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Two way binding a double does indeed give some issues in Windows Store apps (input validation, localization, ...). What I usually do is have another property that represents this double as a **string** and bind the string value. You can also add validation on this string property and check if it does parse to a double with `double.TryParse()`.

Hopefully a better solution for Windoew 10 UWP will be announced in the near future to prevent the need for this hack.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. I was also thinking like this but its very time consuming way for me because there are large number of properties I need to bind with UI. In other way with help of converter, in convertback() will check for double.TryParse() and if not then return the double.MaxValue and handle the same value in custom validation class. Please give me your suggestion for the same.

Comment: I suppose that works as well. The conclusion is that you can't trust the system to do the conversion for you.